# Track Page Views with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track page views of a site with Google Analytics.

As far as I know I need to send the URL of the page to GA.

But sometimes the URL might change in the future even if it is the same page.

Shouldn't I send info on the page instead of the URL? Something like:

Track("Contact Page").

How should I do it and does Google Analytics allow that?

Thank you,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to force Google Analytics to use a set string for a page that would remain static. Per the documentation:

[new style](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding):

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '{static url here}');
```

[old style](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '{static url here}']);
```

But a warning, renaming page URLs could do some harm to your search engine ranking over time and frustrate your users.

Comment: Usually I do not rename url's ... But of course that can happen ... So I am not sure if using a custom string to identify the page wouldn't be better then a real url.

Comment: @MDMoura If you're worried about that, I'd go with Aaron's route and track an event. Both sets of documentation state the parameter is a URL. So I'd be hesitant to use a string of text there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the URL changing for the same page, and you want to aggregate this data, rather than it being divided by URL, I would recommend using [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) to track things on your site - you could create a custom variable for page name (Contact page), or for a certain type of user (Male, Female, etc.), or for a session (Bob Jones from Iowa).